# Returning the K biggest element from an array. (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static Word[] simpleSelect(Word[] array, int k){
    k= array.length;
    for(int i = 0; i< k-1; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<k-i-1; j++){
            if(array[j].compareTo(array[j+1]) < 0){
                swap(array,j, j+1); 
            }
        }           
    }
    return array;
}
```

I created this above code to return the `K` biggest elements from an array through a bubble sort. I am suppose to make this method `O(nk)`. 
I have wrote this code and figured that the returned array doesn't print an array with `k` size. Instead, it just prints the original array with the same length, just bubble sorted.

For example, if I my original array is `{1,19, 7 ,26 ,9 ,85}` and my `k` value is `2`, I want it to return `{85,26}`.
Instead, currently this code is returning `{85,26,19,9,7,1}` no matter what the `k` value is.

I would like to know what i am doing wrong here and also would like to know if I am coding right in `O(nk)` times.

Comment: If you want to have a smaller array (or basically any array that's different from the original) you need a copy of the sorted array, e.g. `Arrays.copyOf(array, 2)`

Comment: `k= array.length` ... you are modifying your argument to the length of the array and  sorting it

Answer (score 1):

1. `k` is re-assigned on line 2: `k = array.length;` it's the reason why the method behaves regardless of the value of `k`.
2. As for complexity [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) has an average complexity of O(n^2), it must be adapted to meet your O(nk) requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have the following array of numbers

```
static int[] arr = {456, 12 , 998, 546, 12,  987, 6456, 66, 9789};
```

We are going to construct the array of k largest numbers by iteratively finding the largest number of the array and then marking that number so that it does not get picked again.

This is the method that will find the k largest elements:

```
private static int[] kLargest(int[] arr, int k){
    int[] klargest = new int[k];
    for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
        klargest[i] = findAndMarkLargest(arr);
    }
    return klargest;
}
```

And this is the method that find the single largest element, and then marks it (by setting the elements to Integer.MIN_VALUE)

```
private static int findAndMarkLargest(int[] arr){
    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i] > largest){
            largest = arr[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i] == largest){
            arr[i] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

The main method (that simply calls the kLargest method) looks like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    // your code goes here
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(kLargest(arr, 3)));
}
```

And outputs:

> [9789, 6456, 998]

Each call to `findAndMarkLargest` takes 2*n operations (since it runs over the array twice).

The method `findAndMarkLargest` is called k times by 'kLargest'. So, in terms of big O notation, this is O(2kn) which is equivalent to O(nk)